# Connection constantly closing with Python websockets

Tags: python, api, websocket

I've tried setting up a WebSocket server, and an API to access it via browser

I'm a week new into Python, and I hope this somewhat makes sense.

I have a Server class

```
**Server.py**
# WS server that sends messages at random intervals
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets

async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
        await websocket.send(now)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)


async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)


async def router(websocket, path):
    if path == "/get":
        await time(websocket)
    elif path == "/post":
        await echo(websocket)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(router, "127.0.0.1", 8081, ping_interval=None))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

and an API class

```
**API.py**
from quart import Quart
import json
import websockets

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/get',methods=['GET'])
async def foo1():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8081"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        try:
            receivedMessage = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"< {receivedMessage}")
        except:
            print('Reconnecting')
            websocket = await websockets.connect(uri)

    return ' '

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
async def foo2():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8081"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Hello world!")
        try:
            await websocket.recv()
        except:
            print('Reconnecting')
            websocket = await websockets.connect(uri)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

My aim was to be able to access different functions from the Server, based on the API's Path which was being accessed (seen it here: https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/547)

The problem I'm getting is that "Reconnecting" appears constantly, and nothing actually happens when I make use of /get or /post (i.e. it seems to be closing after .recv() occurs - I know this because I had seen ConnectionClosedOk - no reason 1000 earlier.

I really don't understand what I'm doing right now lol, it is very confusing. **I did get things to work when Server only had 1 function** (constantly spitting out timestamps), and the API only had a GET function (to display the current time of the request).. things now don't really work after **I implemented the router function.**

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. My Python knowledge is incredibly limited, so as verbose an answer as possible would really help me out.

I'm assuming that the POST method is going to result in "Hello world!" appearing on the console for the Server, but I'm probably wrong about that :( I just seen it in some tutorial documentation.

**EDIT: Also, I'm not able to access localhost:(port)/post; it says Specified method is invalid for this resource; why is that?**

Comment: I cannot help you, but could you indicate which version of Python you are using.